# Show that purity = 1 in a pure state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator

How can you show that for **any** pure state, the purity = 1?

Pure state: $\rho^2 = \rho$ and $Tr(\rho^2)=1$

Mixed state: $\rho^2 \neq \rho$ and  $Tr(\rho^2)<1$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a pure state, by definition, 
$$\rho = |\psi\rangle\langle \psi| $$
So it is a projection operator onto the pure state $|\psi\rangle$. Note that ${\rm Tr}(\rho L)=\langle\psi|L|\psi\rangle$ for this density matrix. So it follows that
$$\rho^2 = |\psi\rangle\langle \psi|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|=|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|=\rho $$
and ${\rm Tr}(\rho^2)=1$ follows from the usual normalization conditions for the overall probability ${\rm Tr}(\rho)=\langle\psi|\psi\rangle=1$.

Comment: Brilliant! This method is what I used, I was concerned that there is a more rigorous way of proving this.

Comment: Why don't you consider the above method rigorous enough ?

Comment: It was more that I wasn't sure if there was another way.

Using this technique, I also proved that $Tra(\rho)<1$